# Getting "Invalid Partition Table" after installing 16.04 LTS on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

Greeting from Vietnam. I'm totally new with Linux, but really want to start learning.

My first try was installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my W10 laptop. I followed instructions on the Internet and successfully installed the Ubuntu and really got excited
But when I tried to restart the machine, then it does not allow me to directly boot to either Windows or Ubuntu. All I got is always the message "Invalid Partition Table".

To proceed further, I have to choose try Ubuntu (after choosing to boot from the USB), or press F12 (for Dell laptop - in my case) and choose Windows Boot Manager.

After searching for several solutions on the Internet, I came up with the GParted table as below (I could not insert the picture as a new registration)

```
/dev/sda6 (w/ key icon) ----- linux-swap ----- (no flag)
/dev/sda7 ----- ext4 ----- (no flag)
/dev/sda8 ----- unkown ----- bios_grub
```

So anyone please can help to solve my problem?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: "instructions on the internet" seems a bit vague. Please edit your question to provide a link to the exact instructions you followed.

Comment: "instructions on the internet" doesn't help us understand where you went wrong. However, for your convenience, you can take help from this link `https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/`

I am sure this link will help you understand where you went wrong in installation process. 

Also, for "Invalid partition table" on boot, may be this link `https://neosmart.net/wiki/invalid-partition-table/` helps you.

Comment: Thank you user535733 for your comment, but to be honest I did not remember which link that I followed, as at that time I was seeing several websites.

Comment: @mAnN: thanks a lot for your recommendation. I will try those links and come back to you soon.

Comment: sure @manhcuong2407. Will wait for your updates.